# How to download and Install APL?

Tags: installation, apl

I want to work with [APL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_(programming_language)) programming language, I have searched for hours and I couldn't figure out how to install it, the only useful stuff I found was the APL keyboard and such a mentioned [here](http://tryapl.org/). So my question is, how can I properly install it?

Comment: What kind of system do you want to install it on? Windows?  Linux?  Mac?  z/OS?  And what sort of APL do you want? -- Free open source for learning? Commercial industrial strength for production use?

Comment: @EvansWinner I just want to simulate some economic models on my own personal laptop (using windows) for an university project :) so I guess just a community licence would be sufficient for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[tryapl.org](http://tryapl.org) uses [Dyalog APL](http://dyalog.com), so I will assume you're interested in getting a licence, downloading and installing that. The licenses for personal use of Dyalog APL are free, so you need to apply for personal, non-commercial license using [the form](http://dss.dyalog.com/apply.php?ltype=pe) on their website. Following that, you'll get an email with instructions for download & installaton :-)

P.S: Dyalog is available for Windows, Linux and Mac OS.

Comment: Glad I could help :-)

Answer (score 2):

or have a look at http://www.gnu.org/software/apl/
which is free.

Jürgen

Answer (score 1):

Try NGN APL, it works in the browser.

http://ngn.github.io/apl/web/index.html

Comment: Thank you, however, I want to use APL for a university project so I guess this wouldn't be suitable for me.

Answer (score 1):

Nars2000 is a free GPL apl that runs natively on Windows and has a nice installer and gui.  http://www.nars2000.org/

Answer (score 1):

For the Mac:

brew install gnu-apl